# Polling and on demand function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a JQuery function that polls the server. I now wanted to add an onClick function to the loading icon so that if the user presses the icon it will refresh on demand. 
The polling works fine until I press the icon. It then stops polling and every time I press the icon it creates double the amount of calls. So first time 1, second time 2 third time 4 and so on. I am a JQuery newbie so I am not sure if I should create two functions on for just polling and one for refresh.

```
var DO_POLLING = {

    load: function doPoll(poll) {
     //This part of the call is a PlayFramework spefic part but it works the same as vanila jquery
     var ajax = jsRoutes.controllers.AjaxApplication.getAjaxReceipts(ll).ajax ( {
      beforeSend : function () {
        //
      },
      success : function ( data ) {
        //
      },
      complete : function ( data ) {
        //
      },
      always : function ( data ) {
        if(poll){
          setTimeout(doPoll,30000);
        }
      },
      error : function ( ) {
        //
      }
    }
    );

    //This is called when the refresh icon is called
    $('#wid-id-2 i.fa-refresh').click( function() {
      doPoll(false)
    })
}
}

$(document).ready(function () {
   DO_POLLING.load(true);
});
```

Comment: your code does not seem to do a polling since it is never passes `true` to the `doPoll` method

Comment: Well spotted, edited to show the true in the initial call.

Answer (score 1):

You are adding a click handler each time the `doPoll` method is called.

You need to either restructure your object, so the the init method will do the binding and another will do the polling or just unbind the handler before re-binding

So the easy solution would be to do

```
$('#wid-id-2 i.fa-refresh').unbind('click').click( function() {
  doPoll(false);
});
```

Comment: Ok understand, the easy solution only half works because once I add it the polling stops, but it's ok since the better solution is as you suggested to restructure the method so that the polling and binding are done separately.